# graphtimer v2 - Utility to plot timings

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, matplotlib

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/Peilonrayz/graphtimer) (MIT)
Clone the repo and replace the contents of `example.py` with the one at the bottom and you'll have everything setup.

## Explanation of the code

A long while ago I posted the question "[Abstract graphing-and-timing functions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/146434)".
It was a god class, wasn't extendable/configurable, you also had to use strings to interact with `timeit`.
And it just wasn't clear what was what.

A little while ago I posted an answer where I used a couple ikky `timeit.timeit` calls rather than build a graph. And Graipher showed me a nice looking graph. I've continued to see these nice graphs, with no easy way to make them myself. And so I decided I needed to way-too-early-spring clean my code.

1. (`timer.py`) A `Timer` object should be in charge of building and calling `timeit`.
   This object was based of `timeit.Timer`, however I thought it needed some additional functionality:

   1. It should be able to time multiple functions.
   2. It should be able to test against multiple values.
   3. It should only perform timings.
2. (`graph.py`) A graph class should be introduced that plots the data in the correct way. If you want to plot in something that isn't `matplotlib` then you just need to change the class.
3. (`plotter.py`) Statistical analysis should not be in either the `Timer` or the graph class. I also kept the analysis to be pretty basic as per the [Python docs suggestion](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.repeat).
4. (`plotter.py`) Performing all the above should be simple with good defaults. And so `Plotter` handles interacting with everything. Whilst it's a small wrapper it means that I, and other, don't have to write that many lines to get the wanted graph.

## What I'd like out of a review.

1. The thing I find most important right now is, [is the design good](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1926)?

   Is `Plotter` a poor design pattern? Is splitting the code out like I have done a bad idea?
2. Is the usage for a user clean and readable?
3. Is there a way to make my code more readable? I find `MatPlotLib` to be a bit on the not so clean side.
4. Any and all critiques are welcome.

## Code

(I have left out some code, and the .pyi files. These are available [on GitHub](https://github.com/Peilonrayz/graphtimer).)

`graph.py`

```
from .graphtimer import CATEGORY10


class MatPlotLib:
    def _graph_times(self, graph, data, domain, colors, error, fmt):
        for results, color in zip(data, colors):
            values = [v.value for v in results]
            if error:
                errors = zip(*[v.errors or [] for v in results])
                for error in errors:
                    lower, upper = zip(*error)
                    graph.fill_between(domain, upper, lower, facecolor=color, edgecolor=None, alpha=0.1)
            yield graph.plot(domain, values, fmt, color=color)[0]

    def graph(self, graph, data, domain, *, functions=None, colors=CATEGORY10, title=None, legend=True, error=True,
              x_label='Input', y_label='Time [s]', fmt='-'):
        lines = list(self._graph_times(graph, data, domain, colors, error, fmt))
        if x_label is not None:
            graph.set_xlabel(x_label)
        if y_label is not None:
            graph.set_ylabel(y_label)
        if title is not None and hasattr(graph, 'set_title'):
            graph.set_title(title)
        if legend and functions is not None and hasattr(graph, 'legend'):
            graph.legend(lines, [fn.__name__ for fn in functions], loc=0)
        return lines
```

`timers.py`

```
import timeit

SENTINAL = object()


class MultiTimer:
    """Interface to timeit.Timer to ease timing over multiple functions."""
    def __init__(self, functions, timer=timeit.Timer):
        self.timer = timer
        self.functions = functions

    def build_timer(self, fn, domain, stmt='fn(*args)', setup='pass', timer=SENTINAL, globals=SENTINAL,
                    args_conv=SENTINAL):
        """Build a timeit.Timer"""
        if not isinstance(domain, tuple):
            domain = domain,
        if args_conv is not SENTINAL:
            domain = args_conv(*domain)
            if not isinstance(domain, tuple):
                domain = domain,

        if globals is SENTINAL:
            globals = {}
        else:
            globals = globals.copy()
        globals.update({'fn': fn, 'args': domain})

        # print(f'{self.timer}({stmt!r}, {setup!r}, {timer!r}, {globals!r})')

        if timer is SENTINAL:
            timer = timeit.default_timer

        return self.timer(stmt, setup, timer, globals=globals)

    def build_timers(self, domain, *args, **kwargs):
        """Build multiple timers from various inputs and functions"""
        return [
            [
                self.build_timer(fn, dom, *args, **kwargs)
                for fn in self.functions
            ]
            for dom in domain
        ]

    def _call(self, domain, repeat, call, *args, **kwargs):
        """Helper function to generate timing data."""
        if len(domain) == 0:
            raise ValueError('domain must have at least one argument.')

        functions = self.build_timers(domain, *args, **kwargs)
        output = [[[] for _ in domain] for _ in functions[0]]
        for _ in range(repeat):
            for j, fns in enumerate(functions):
                for i, fn in enumerate(fns):
                    output[i][j].append(call(fn))
        return output

    def repeat(self, domain, repeat, number, *args, **kwargs):
        """Interface to timeit.Timer.repeat. `domain` is the values to pass to the functions."""
        return self._call(domain, repeat, lambda f: f.timeit(number), *args, **kwargs)

    def timeit(self, domain, number, *args, **kwargs):
        """Interface to timeit.Timer.timeit. `domain` is the values to pass to the functions."""
        return [
            [value[0] for value in values]
            for values in self.repeat(domain, 1, number, *args, **kwargs)
        ]

    def autorange(self, domain, *args, **kwargs):
        """Interface to timeit.Timer.autorange. `domain` is the values to pass to the functions."""
        return [
            [value[0] for value in values]
            for values in self._call(domain, 1, lambda f: f.autorange(), *args, **kwargs)
        ]


class TimerNamespaceMeta(type):
    """Convenience class to ease creation of a MultiTimer."""
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        if 'functions' in attrs:
            raise TypeError('FunctionTimers cannot define `functions`')
        if 'multi_timer' in attrs:
            raise TypeError('FunctionTimers cannot define `multi_timer`')

        ret: TimerNamespace = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)
        functions = [v for k, v in attrs.items() if k.startswith('test')]
        ret.functions = functions
        ret.multi_timer = ret.MULTI_TIMER(functions, ret.TIMER)
        return ret


class TimerNamespace(metaclass=TimerNamespaceMeta):
    """Convenience class to ease creation of a MultiTimer."""
    TIMER = timeit.Timer
    MULTI_TIMER = MultiTimer
```

`plotter.py`

```
from .graph import MatPlotLib


class Plotter:
    """Interface to the timer object. Returns objects made to ease usage."""
    def __init__(self, timer):
        self.timer = getattr(timer, 'multi_timer', timer)

    def timeit(self, number, domain, *args, **kwargs):
        """Interface to self.timer.timeit. Returns a PlotValues."""
        return self.repeat(1, number, domain, *args, **kwargs).min(errors=None)

    def repeat(self, repeat, number, domain, *args, **kwargs):
        """Interface to self.timer.repeat. Returns a PlotTimings."""
        return PlotTimings(
            self.timer.repeat(domain, repeat, number, *args, **kwargs),
            {
                'functions': self.timer.functions,
                'domain': domain
            }
        )


class _DataSet:
    """Holds timeit values and defines statistical methods around them."""
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = sorted(values)

    def quartile_indexes(self, outlier):
        """Generates the quartile indexes. Uses tukey's fences to remove outliers."""
        delta = (len(self.values) - 1) / 4
        quartiles = [int(round(delta * i)) for i in range(5)]
        if outlier is not None:
            if outlier < 0:
                raise ValueError("outlier should be non-negative.")
            iqr = outlier * (self.values[quartiles[3]] - self.values[quartiles[1]])
            low = self.values[quartiles[1]] - iqr
            high = self.values[quartiles[3]] + iqr

            for i, v in enumerate(self.values):
                if v >= low:
                    quartiles[0] = i
                    break

            for i, v in reversed(list(enumerate(self.values))):
                if v <= high:
                    quartiles[4] = i
                    break
        return tuple(quartiles)

    def errors(self, errors, outlier):
        """Returns tuples containing the quartiles wanted."""
        if errors is None:
            return None
        quartiles = self.quartile_indexes(outlier)
        # Allow out of quartile error bars using -1 and 5.
        quartiles += (-1, 0)
        return [
            (
                self.values[quartiles[start]],
                self.values[quartiles[stop]]
            )
            for start, stop in errors
        ]

    def quartile(self, quartile, outlier):
        """Return the value of the quartile provided."""
        quartiles = self.quartile_indexes(outlier)
        return self.values[quartiles[quartile]]

    def mean(self, start, end, outlier):
        """Return the mean of the values over the quartiles specified."""
        quartiles = self.quartile_indexes(outlier)
        start = quartiles[start]
        end = quartiles[end]
        return sum(self.values[start:end + 1]) / (1 + end - start)


class PlotTimings:
    """Thin interface over _DataSet"""
    def __init__(self, data, kwargs):
        self.data = [
            [_DataSet(results) for results in function_values]
            for function_values in data
        ]
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def quartile(self, quartile, *, errors=None, outlier=1.5):
        """Interface to _DataSet.quartile and errors. Returns a PlotValues."""
        return PlotValues(
            [
                [
                    _DataValues(
                        ds.quartile(quartile, outlier),
                        ds.errors(errors, outlier)
                    )
                    for ds in function_values
                ]
                for function_values in self.data
            ],
            self.kwargs
        )

    def min(self, *, errors=((-1, 3),), outlier=1.5):
        """Return the Q1 value and show the error from Q-1 Q3."""
        return self.quartile(0, errors=errors, outlier=outlier)

    def max(self, *, errors=((1, 5),), outlier=1.5):
        """Return the Q4 value and show the error from Q1 Q5."""
        return self.quartile(4, errors=errors, outlier=outlier)

    def mean(self, start=0, end=4, *, errors=((1, 3),), outlier=1.5):
        """Interface to _DataSet.mean and errors. Returns a PlotValues."""
        return PlotValues(
            [
                [
                    _DataValues(
                        ds.mean(start, end, outlier),
                        ds.errors(errors, outlier)
                    )
                    for ds in function_values
                ]
                for function_values in self.data
            ],
            self.kwargs
        )


class _DataValues:
    """Holds the wanted statistical data from the timings."""
    def __init__(self, value, errors):
        self.value = value
        self.errors = errors


class PlotValues:
    """Thin interface to Graph.graph."""
    def __init__(self, data, kwargs):
        self.data = data
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def plot(self, graph, graph_lib=MatPlotLib, **kwargs):
        g = graph_lib()
        return g.graph(
            graph,
            self.data,
            self.kwargs.pop('domain'),
            functions=self.kwargs.pop('functions'),
            **kwargs
        )
```

## Example usage

I've included the same graph as I did on my old code. And two of Graipher's graphs.

1. [Abstract graphing-and-timing functions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/146434) - This is to ensure usage is simple in abnormal usage.
   It also shows that you can plot multiple error areas, highlighted in the unoptimised graph.
2. [Plot timings for a range of inputs](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/165245) - This is to make sure standard usage is simple.
3. [String reversal in Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/215181) - This is so I know logerithmic graphs display correctly.

   I'm running on Windows and don't have a C compiler, and so I can't include the additional two functions. However I think it nicely shows why the Python docs say to use `min`.

```
import time
import math

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from graphtimer import flat, Plotter, TimerNamespace


class UnoptimisedRange(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if i >= self.size:
            raise IndexError()
        return i


class Peilonrayz(TimerNamespace):
    def test_comprehension(iterable):
        return [i for i in iterable]

    def test_append(iterable):
        a = []
        append = a.append
        for i in iterable:
            append(i)
        return a


SCALE = 10.


class Graipher(TimerNamespace):
    def test_o_n(n):
        time.sleep(n / SCALE)

    def test_o_n2(n):
        time.sleep(n ** 2 / SCALE)

    def test_o_log(n):
        time.sleep(math.log(n + 1) / SCALE)

    def test_o_exp(n):
        time.sleep((math.exp(n) - 1) / SCALE)

    def test_o_nlog(n):
        time.sleep(n * math.log(n + 1) / SCALE)


class Reverse(TimerNamespace):
    def test_orig(stri):
        output = ''
        length = len(stri)
        while length > 0:
            output += stri[-1]
            stri, length = (stri[0:length - 1], length - 1)
        return output

    def test_g(s):
        return s[::-1]

    def test_s(s):
        return ''.join(reversed(s))


def main():
    # Reverse
    fig, axs = plt.subplots()
    axs.set_yscale('log')
    axs.set_xscale('log')
    (
        Plotter(Reverse)
            .repeat(10, 10, np.logspace(0, 5), args_conv=lambda i: ' '*int(i))
            .min()
            .plot(axs, title='Reverse', fmt='-o')
    )
    fig.show()

    # Graipher
    fig, axs = plt.subplots()
    (
        Plotter(Graipher)
            .repeat(2, 1, [i / 10 for i in range(10)])
            .min()
            .plot(axs, title='Graipher', fmt='-o')
    )
    fig.show()

    # Peilonrayz
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
    p = Plotter(Peilonrayz)
    axis = [
        ('Range', {'args_conv': range}),
        ('List', {'args_conv': lambda i: list(range(i))}),
        ('Unoptimised', {'args_conv': UnoptimisedRange}),
    ]
    for graph, (title, kwargs) in zip(iter(flat(axs)), axis):
        (
            p.repeat(100, 5, list(range(0, 10001, 1000)), **kwargs)
                .min(errors=((-1, 3), (-1, 4)))
                .plot(graph, title=title)
        )
    fig.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: My graphs]
[image: Graipher's graphs]
[image: Reverse graphs]